# CoreData with autosave saves 1st time, then crashes with "NoSuchFileError" on all following autosaves

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, nsdocument

NSDocument-based application using CoreData. Very simple - two entities, with a one-to-many relationship. This app works perfectly with save, load, etc.

Then I turned on autosave like this:

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] setAutosavingDelay:0.1];
```

...and immediately it went horribly wrong.

The first autosave works, 100% correctly. i.e. it saves a file in the user's private directory, and if you quit the app and restart, the autosaved-doc automatically re-opens. Cool!

But as soon as you make a second change to the data, you get a crash in the autosave, with this:

```
error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x1001a1be0 "An error occurred while saving."
 Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo=0x10019a840 "The file doesn’t exist."
 Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo=0x100150d00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"))
```

...which makes no sense to me. Why would auto*SAVE* care about whether a file exists or not? Why would it work the first time, then fail on subsequent times?

NB: I've checked, and Apple attemtps to use the identical filename on the second autosave call - if it worked first time, why did it fail 0.5 seconds later???

Answer (score 1):

Why are you attempting to auto-save ten times per second? That's WAY too often. It may take longer than a tenth of a second to actually save your file. A saner value would be 10 seconds and that's probably more frequent than is actually necessary.

Comment: My understanding of the docs is that while it's saving, it won't autosave again (unless some data is modified while saving?). The 0.1 seconds was to make testing / debugging faster, and I assumed it wouldn't have an effect on whether the saving is working or not - do you think that's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, this appears to be a known flaw of Apple's implementation of Core Data with NSDocument: autosave is broken, and they don't intend to fix it.

From NSPersistentDocument (the subclass of NSDocument that is used when you select Core Data and NSDocument at project creation time):

> “Save To…” and Autosave are not
>   directly supported—Core Data cannot
>   save to a store and maintain the same
>   changed state in the managed object
>   context, all the while maintaining an
>   unsaved stack as the current document.

Interesting claim that "Core Data cannot..." - surely, CD "can" do this, although I can see it's probably a lot of code and jumping through hoops to make it work. Sounds more like an excuse than an explanation.